# Why pool.imap() does not even execute one task at Jupyter Notebook?

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, multiprocessing

Even a very simple piece of code does not return anything but always keeps running.

```
pool = mp.Pool(processes=10)
def add1(x):
    return x + 1
for x in pool.imap(add1, [1,2,3]):
    print(x)
pool.close()
```

And any other operations can not be done if it's running, including shutting down the kernel!

Comment: I found pool.imap() does not even call the defined function, but just stuck there..

Comment: you'd have to give more details, any output / errors, if not then OS / version numbers would help.  see https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve for what makes a good question

Answer (score 0):

Multiprocessing only works reliably when you're doing it from a file. If you are on a Mac or Windows, multiprocessing starts a new Python process.  That Python process reads the file from which it was started in order to know its own code, but doesn't execute the `__main__` code.  It then executes what it was to execute.

This process doesn't work with Jupyter because there is no Python file to read.

Multithreading should work fine.

Comment: Thank you! I did use Jupyter... Now it works on Pycharm.

Comment: Sometime multithreading just won't suffice.. If  function `add1` is imported from a module, then it should work with multiprocessing. running with Jupyter Notebook